# How to display all the items from Async Storage in react Native

Tags: react-native, async-await, asyncstorage

I want to display all the items, like if I have stored 5 items, 5  Elements are shown with there respective information which is there in the items.

I want to add/remove items also.

I have used this

```
getAllKeys = async () => {
  let keys = []
  try {
    keys = await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
  } catch(e) {
    // read key error
  }

  console.log(keys)
  // example console.log result:
  // ['@MyApp_user', '@MyApp_key']
}
```

But getting an error.

If I use state with **useEffect** then it becomes an infinite loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to use the second arguments of useEffect?
It lets you  define an array of variable to watch in order to rerun the effect.
If you use an empty array it means that the effect is called only at the first rendering.

```
const [keys, setKeys] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {

   AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
    .then(setKeys)
    .catch(e => {}//handle error)

}, [] //no variable in watch so it get fired only the first time)
```

Comment: Ya but after that, it works only once, and when I add a new item to it, it does not work.

Comment: You forgot to mention that you have to add/remove items. Probably the cleanest way to do it should be to pass keys as props from the parent component

Comment: Ya, I edited it, I will add my code so that it becomes easy what actually I am getting the problem. Thanks for responding.